# Is there a better way than self-assign value for the Livedata to update view?

Tags: java, android, android-livedata, android-lint

For Android's LiveData, I sometimes use self-assignment so that my views can be updated.

For example:

```
fun retry() {
    myModel.setLoadingRetry()
    loadStatesMap
        .forEach {
            it.value.first?.value = t.value.first?.value
        }
    retryCallback?.invoke()
}
```

However, it makes Sonarqube code quality bug, since it it not usual.
Bug description:

> There is no reason to re-assign a variable to itself. Either this
>   statement is redundant and should be removed, or the re-assignment is
>   a mistake and some other value or variable was intended for the
>   assignment instead.

I guess I can update views by not self-assigning my Livedata value.
If anyone have an idea, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could call `Observer:onChanged(T)` instead of self-assigning value.